# How to get macOS Wi-Fi device name programmatically in Bash script?

Tags: wifi, cron

```
bash% networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder
An asterisk (*) denotes that a network service is disabled.
(1) SAMSUNG Modem
(Hardware Port: Modem (SAMSUNG_MDM), Device: SAMSUNG_MDM)

(2) Ethernet
(Hardware Port: Ethernet, Device: en0)

(3) FireWire
(Hardware Port: FireWire, Device: fw0)

(4) Wi-Fi
(Hardware Port: Wi-Fi, Device: en1)

(5) Bluetooth PAN
(Hardware Port: Bluetooth PAN, Device: en2)
```

This is good for reading but how do I get 'en1' programmatically in a Bash script so I can use the device name in a cron job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your question I know you used `networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder` however I'd use `networksetup -listallhardwareports` instead as it's easier to parse the output using `awk`, by itself, with a minimum of coding so as to avoid multiple *pipes* using several other *commands* as offered in the other answer and should be robust enough to produce consistent output until Apple changes the output format of `networksetup -listallhardwareports`, if they ever do.

As an example on my system, `networksetup -listallhardwareports` shows the following:

```
$ networksetup -listallhardwareports

Hardware Port: Bluetooth DUN
Device: Bluetooth-Modem
Ethernet Address: N/A

Hardware Port: Display Ethernet
Device: en3
Ethernet Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

Hardware Port: Display FireWire
Device: fw0
Ethernet Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

Hardware Port: Wi-Fi
Device: en0
Ethernet Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

Hardware Port: Bluetooth PAN
Device: en2
Ethernet Address: N/A

VLAN Configurations
===================
$
```

Looking at the relevant lines of output:

```
Hardware Port: Wi-Fi
Device: en0
```

The easiest way to get `en0`, in this example is:

```
networksetup -listallhardwareports | awk '/Wi-Fi/{getline; print $2}'
```

It can be assigned to a variable:

```
wifiDevice="$(networksetup -listallhardwareports | awk '/Wi-Fi/{getline; print $2}')"
```

You can then use `$wifiDevice` later in the script to represent `en0`, in this example.

Obviously on your system, based on the output in your question, `$wifiDevice` would be: `en1`

---

If you want to use `networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder`then you can use `awk`, by itself, in this manner:

```
networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | awk '{gsub(/\)/, "")}/Wi-Fi, Device/{print $5}'
```

However, I'd use my first example over this.

---

I'd also stay away from using `system_profiler` in this case, as it takes considerably longer for the output to be generated then when using `networksetup`.

Comment: Good answer, but `system_profiler` doesn't take any more time to generate the output when you specify the data type that you want:  `system_profiler SPAirPortDataType`  What takes the time is when it has to generate *all* the data types.

Comment: @Allan, I'm not talking about running `system_profiler` with no argument! I'm comparing the actual time it takes running `networksetup -listallhardwareports` vs. `system_profiler SPAirPortDataType`, where e.g. on my system the former is instantaneous in comparison to the latter, `0m0.025s` vs. `0m3.296s`! At ~130 times faster, it's no contest and why I made the remark.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output  `grep` `awk` and `cut` as an option:

```
networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | grep -i "Wi-Fi, Device" | awk '{ print $5 }' | cut -c 1-3
```

You can also use `system_profiler` to get details about your AirPort adapter:

`system_profiler SPAirPortDataType`

Then, you can again, pipe that output through grep to get your adapter:

`system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | grep Interfaces -A1`

Comment: Not terribly robust; I was hoping for some more built-in function with options to get that. For example, the behavior of 'grep' on different machines can vary, making the following cut command not always correct.

Comment: Help me understand this - you don't know how to get this in bash, but you know it's not "robust" enough.  What exactly do you want to do because now your question is lacking substantial details.  What "built in function" would you like?

Comment: Instead of piping the output of `networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder` first to `grep`, then to `awk`, then to `cut`, just use `awk` for the whole process, e.g.: `networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | awk '{gsub(/\)/, "")}/Wi-Fi, Device/{print $5}'`